# Best way to phrase a 2 x 2 list

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I'm working on the website for a theater that teaches improv classes and sketch classes, and also features improv shows and sketch shows.

The front page of the website lists: "Improv and Sketch Classes and Shows," which sounds okay, but doesn't strike me as particularly clear or well-put.

Is there a succinct way to express this 2x2 idea, or can anyone suggest a concise way to write around this idea?

Comment: At the very least a comma between the pairs would help. It's arguably incorrect to use a semicolon, but it would be clear what you mean. Even a line break could work if you're laying out something akin to a title.

Comment: Actually, a line break works really well, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Classes and Shows in both Improv and Sketches?

Answer (score 0):

It would be clearer to add an extra word to avoid unduly linking the terms between the two *and*s.

> Classes and Shows about Improv and Sketch

Answer (score 0):

I would make a title and subtitle.

**Improv and Sketch.**
*Our [offer of] Classes and Shows*